# What is the part of a printer called that holds the ink cartridges?

Tags: printer, ink

What is the part of a printer called that holds the ink cartridges? I believe it is called a "carriage," but I have seen other names for it. What is the official or actual term for it? Thanks!

Comment: There isn't a universal name, and different printers have different configurations.  Some have the cartidges in a fixed location, some plug into the print head.  If they plug into the print head, the moving piece that holds the cartridges and print head is sometimes called a carriage.

Answer (score 0):

I know no official name, but I would assume you could call it a 'clip', or even 'cartridge-clip'. Maybe the word 'magazine' could also apply, however this is usually reserved for a clip which also has springs or mechanisms to facilitate release or loading.

From [Cambridge dictionaries online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clip)

> clip noun  (FASTENER)   › a ​small ​object usually made of ​metal or
>   ​plastic, used for ​fastening things together or ​holding them in
>   ​position